# How do I select each box for styling there are three class and the box child class only says box but there are 10 of them

Tags: html, css

How do I style the ten boxes, when I tried to with the parent it style all the ten box at the same  time... I tried to rename each class of the box child so I can style them but it didn't work How do I select to style each box with individual back-ground color.... also when I tried to get the image on the navigation I got nothing and when I copy the image link from inspection tool the logo wasn't there I only got the image.

```
<section class="middle-content">

  <h2>Why Did It Have To Be Boxes...</h2>

  <div class="boxes">
    <div class="box">Box 1</div>
    <div class="box">Box 2</div>
    <div class="box">Box 3</div>
    <div class="box">Box 4</div>
    <div class="box">Box 5</div>
    <div class="box">Box 6</div>
    <div class="box">Box 7</div>
    <div class="box">Box 8</div>
    <div class="box">Box 9</div>
    <div class="box">Box 10</div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [:nth-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child)

```
.boxes .box:nth-child(1) {  
 color: lime; 
}
```

fiddle-> https://jsfiddle.net/hansfelix50/58qefsxb/

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `nth-child` selector. It can accept a single `index` for the element you want to target (starts at index `1`) or you can specify a rule (`3n` would mean each `third` element)

```css
.box:nth-child(1) {
  background: yellow;
}

.box:nth-child(2) {
  background: red;
}

.box:nth-child(3n) {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<section class="middle-content">

<h2>Why Did It Have To Be Boxes...</h2>

<div class="boxes">
<div class="box">Box 1</div>
<div class="box">Box 2</div>
<div class="box">Box 3</div>
<div class="box">Box 4</div>
<div class="box">Box 5</div>
<div class="box">Box 6</div>
<div class="box">Box 7</div>
<div class="box">Box 8</div>
<div class="box">Box 9</div>
<div class="box">Box 10</div>
</div>
</section>
```

Comment: how about 2n and 3n for some of the boxes there are showing no colours??? although i upvoted

Comment: @nikhilsugandh I was just showcasing the possibilities :)